# Multiple Analyzers for query_string by Field

Tags: elasticsearch

for particular query, how can i define separate query analyzers by
field (phonetic_name, name). Just define search_analyzers for phonetic_name & name in Put Mapping of Index/Type?

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["phonetic_name", "name^5"],
        "query" : "italian food",
        "use_dis_max" : true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the analyzer for a field when the index is created, for example:

```
curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex -d '{
  "mappings":{
    "mytype":{
      "properties":{
        "field1":{"store":"yes","index":"not_analyzed","type":"string"},
        "field2":{"store":"yes","analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},
        "field3":{"store":"yes","analyzer":"simple","type":"string"},
      }
    }
  }
}'
```